# Equivalent of Javascripts encodeURI in Powershell?

Tags: javascript, powershell, encodeuricomponent

What is the equivalent of Javascripts `encodeURI()` / `encodURIComponent()` in Powershell?

I'm encoding a URL (need some `%20`s in it) and I hate to do that manually.

Comment: You can use a method from the URI class. `[uri]::EscapeUriString('https://exmaple.com/string with spaces')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can utilize the [System.Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netframework-4.8) class for these cases.

The `encodeURI()` equivalent would be to either use the `EscapeUriString` static method from the class or cast your URI string as a `System.URI` type and access the `AbsoluteUri` property.

```
$uri = 'https://example.com/string with spaces'
# Method 1
[uri]::EscapeUriString($uri)
# Method 2
([uri]$uri).AbsoluteUri

# Output
https://example.com/string%20with%20spaces
```

The `encodeURIComponent()` equivalent can be done using the class's `EscapeDataString` method.

```
$uri = 'https://example.com/string with space&OtherThings=?'
[uri]::EscapeDataString($uri)

#Output

https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fstring%20with%20space%26OtherThings%3D%3F
```

---

Note: You do not have to define a variable (`$uri` in this case). You can just replace that with a quoted string. I only used the variable for readability purposes.